# Flutter desktop | Create app with no window

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using Flutter to develop a desktop application(macOS\Windows\linux) and I want to create an application with no main window at the start.
The app should open only the tray and from the tray, it would be possible to open the main window.

Any idea what should I do if I want the main window to stay closed?

Comment: You will probably need to use native code.

Comment: Any suggestion if I can integrate it with flutter code?